# Selecting a DOM element using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a way to select a DOM element (i.e. to replicate `$('selector')` of jQuery) - in AngularJS using `angular.element`?

Comment: What precisely are you trying to do? The magic of angular is that you generally don't have to do that kinda thing

Comment: I need to access an element which has $index for data in $scope from another element.

Comment: I think you are using angular incorrectly and need to read the documentation and how to think in angular.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.. and i should really think in angular way as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) for `angular.element` seems pretty clear to me in that it repeatedly says "does not support selectors". On the other hand, if you've included jQuery before the `DOMContentLoaded` event, then it would support selectors because it *is* jQuery.

However, if you're trying to select a *random element from the DOM* you should re-think your approach, as it is defeating the purpose of using something such as Angular.

If you're just trying to get a reference to the element on which a directive is running, then you can get that element as an argument to a function you specify as `link`. See the section titled "Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM" here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: ng-click="derp()" is certainly the 'more angular way' for instances where you need to operate on an element within the scope of the current controller. jqLite provides support for lots of sub element selections as well https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. And should i use `require: '^myTabs',` in a directive instead of trying a way to select the element?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am about to save some content lets say `$scope.data` which is an array and i have `ng-repeat`-ed it and i have an button to save it. and i am using `ng-click` directive to access a function to save. now i need to know which data has been changed/modified in `$scope.data` as my save button dont know on which `$index` i am modifying...

Comment: well you can pass `$index` in... `ng-click="doSomethingWith($index)"` or you can set a `$watch` function: `$scope.$watch('data', function() { ...`

Comment: i can but save isn't in the scope of `ng-repeat` so as far as i know `$index` wont work in `ng-click="doSomethingWith($index)"`

Comment: `$scope.$watch` then?